# From edge or arc list to clusters in Stata

Tags: social-networking, stata

I have a Stata dataset that represents connections between users that looks like this:

```
src_user linked_user
1         2  
2         3                 
3         5
1         4
6         7
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
user cluster  
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1      
5     1
6     2
7     2
```

where `isid user` evaluates to TRUE and I have grouped all users into disjoint clusters. I have tried thinking of this as a `reshape` problem, but without much success. None of the user-written SNA commands seem to accomplish this as far as I can tell.

What is the most efficient way of doing it with Stata, other than looping, which I am eager to avoid ?

Comment: Just in case you haven't seen it,  this appears to be the concept of connected component.  For example, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: A subsequent question of a similar nature received some guidance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944575/find-social-network-components-in-stata

Answer (score 2):

If you `reshape` the data to long form, you can use `group_id` (from SSC) to get what you want.

```
clear
input user1 user2
1         2  
2         3                 
3         5
1         4
6         7
end

gen id = _n
reshape long user, i(id) j(n)

clonevar cluster = id
list, sepby(cluster)

group_id cluster, match(user)

bysort cluster user (id): keep if _n == 1
list, sepby(cluster)
```