# Find social network components in Stata

Tags: grouping, social-networking, stata

[I copied part of the below example from a separate post and changed it to suit my specific needs]

```
pos_1    pos_2
  2        4
  2        5
  1        2
  3        9
  4        2
  9        3
```

The above is read as person_2 is connected to person_4,...,person_4 is connected to person_2, and person_9 is connected to person_3.

I want to create a third categorical [edited] variable, component, that lets me know if the observed link is part of a connected component (subnetwork) within this network. In this case, there are two connected components in the network:

```
pos_1    pos_2    component
  2        4        1
  2        5        1
  1        2        1
  3        9        2
  4        2        1
  9        3        2
```

All nodes in component 1 are connected to each other, but not to the nodes in component 2 and vice versa. Is there a way to generate this component variable in Stata? I know there are alternative programs to do this in, but my code would be more seamless if I can integrate it into Stata.

Comment: Why is `component` equal to `2` for `3-9` and `9-3` but not `2-4` and `4-2`?

Comment: there is a path connecting 2, 4, 5, and 1 to each other. Thus, they consist one of the components. For example, 1 is connected to 4 through it's connection with 2. 9 and 3 are connected to each other, but there is no path connecting 9 and 3 to any of the other nodes, so they are the second component.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643899/from-edge-or-arc-list-to-clusters-in-stata ? (With no answer yet.) What is different here? Are you sure you have only two connected components?

Comment: I think you'd have to `program` this. I haven't seen code for this task yet. You can find algorithms and references in the Wikipedia site mentioned within my previous link.

Comment: From the Stata Journal there is a Stata graph library for network analysis and accompanying software. It seems to me that the adjacency matrix provides the necessary information to construct the components. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0248 Also, note that the use of dichotomous to describe the component variable is only correct if there are exactly two components.

Comment: Roberto, you're right that it is the same problem as the one you linked to. Also, the use of the word dichotomous is incorrect as William pointed out. There are two components in the example, but in the data there can be more so it is a categorical variable. William, the Stata graph library is useful and I hadn't seen this particular document before. You're right that the adjacency matrix has the necessary information to construct components, so I will likely go that route unless someone has already done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `reshape` the data to long form, you can use `group_id` (from SSC) to get what you want:

```
clear
input pos_1    pos_2
  2        4
  2        5
  1        2
  3        9
  4        2
  9        3
end

gen id = _n
reshape long pos_, i(id) j(n)

clonevar comp = id
list, sepby(comp)

group_id comp, match(pos)

reshape wide pos_, i(id) j(n)

egen component = group(comp)
list
```